# Why is StringSplit dropping empty entries?

Tags: string-manipulation, csv-format

I am parsing a `CSV` and whenever the trailing records are empty:

```
StringSplit[",2,,4,,",","]
```

I get:

> {"2", "", "4"}

But I was expecting:

> {"", "2", "", "4", "", ""}

Is there an option for `StringSplit` to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> By default, StringSplit[s,patt] drops zero-length substrings associated with delimiters that appear at the beginning or end of s.

and

> StringSplit[s,patt,All] returns all substrings, including zero-length ones at the beginning or end.

Comment: Thank you! I should start reading the details section as well. Surprised ChatGPT didn't point this out! It was telling `AllowTrailingDelimiters -> True` which obviously doesn't exist.